# Custom arraySort() algorithm to align elements centrally & pad nulls on either side

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays, array-algorithms

Say I have an array similar to c++ vectors with push and pop inserts/deletes on either side of the array. Whats an efficient way to sort arrays e.g

Arr1 size (NoOfElements) = 3 Capacity = 9
It would look like this:
[null, 1, 2, null, null, null, 3, null, null]

A sort algorithm should sort above array as
[null, null, null, 1, 2, 3, null, null, null]

So basically all elements in the middle and each size padded with null values equally. Of course in certain cases the number of null elements will not always be equals on each side.

Thanks

Edit- The below is a current algorithm I have developed. It takes an array of int values, the capacity(total size) of array and the size (number of elements) in the array. The function SHOULD sort the contents of the array “values” to match above expectation. E.g if an array[10] is passed with size = 5 then there are 5 free spaces. The new array returned from this function should therefore have 3 empty spaces at the front, the 5 elements and 2 empty spaces at the back.

[image]

Comment: what did you do so far? What is blocking you?

Comment: nulls or integers? How are you going to represent your data structure? Using `std::variant` or `std::optional` or tagged unions or something?

Comment: @SumitJha please see edit. Thanks for help

Comment: @Shawn I am actually a dynamic array. I know there are STL container like vectors, but for learning purposes I want to actually implement it.